# Close vote box infa-loads on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app

When I attempt to load the close question box on a site that I don't have enough rep to vote for question closure, the box will show the loading indicator forever. There's no error message or other indication that it has failed to load.

On a related note, on the sites I do have the close vote privilege, the close box takes seemingly forever to load. Sometimes it's faster for me to open the browser, and cast my vote from there instead of waiting for the app. Is it possible to speed this up?

<sup>using v0.1.77</sup>

Comment: A related issue: if you open the close vote dialog on a question that you have already cast a close vote, it will never finish loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in version 1.0.5. The Close option no longer appears if you don't have enough rep to vote to close.

Comment: Yep, fixed due to this related bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217640/close-option-given-before-i-have-the-privilege

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Something possibly related recently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292122/close-vote-dialog-hangs-if-already-voted-to-close