# The Android app no longer has a close option for questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, vote-to-close

I'm using the Android app v1.0.51 on a HTC One with Android 4.4.3. A few weeks ago, I was able to vote to close questions - still during v1.0.51. There's no longer a vote to close option.

[image: open in browser, favourite, share, edit, flag - no close]

I have 18k reputation on this site. Yesterday, I had to open the mobile site to cast close votes.

Comments have reminded me that I can still cast close votes via flagging. This isn't the pattern the site uses, and isn't really user-friendly, evidenced by the fact I thought I had to travel to the mobile site to do this moderation.

Comment: Flag is auto converted to close vote if you have enough reputation. Deleting from within the app was never possible, and [is already requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app).

Comment: Flags are converted, but I do remember the app having explicit *close* option on questions. Now it doesn't. ([Example of a post referring to Close option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218301/259867))

Comment: The same thing has happened to the iOS app! Annoying.

Comment: @Josh yeah, good point! Guess it caused too many bugs and/or caused a security threat so they removed it from the API.

Comment: Do you know that for sure, @ShadowWizard? That would really suck. I figured this was just a oversight/bug.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know it existed, had some bug, and was removed. The rest is assumption.

Comment: Well, I was just proven wrong, @Josh, and glad I did! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was an issue with the API's logic for "Can the user close this" returning false, it's been fixed on the API end and pushed so you should see the Close option everywhere you're supposed to see it again, on both iOS and Android.