# Close-vote dialog hangs if already voted to close

Tags: bug, android-app

In the Android app, if I try to open the "close" dialog on a question after I've already voted to close it, instead of immediately saying "you already voted", or something else to that effect, the dialog just sits there with a spinner and doesn't load. The app isn't frozen, I can "back" out of the dialog, it just never loads anything.

Why would I try to vote twice? I have the attention span of a gnat and sometimes fail to see if I actually hit the close option, or accidentally dismissed the dialog.

Clicking anywhere within the dialog does nothing. Clicking outside of it dismisses it.

App Version 1.0.89

Android 6.0.1, Note 4

Comment: Seems like the android version of [this old ios app bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226471/voting-to-close-on-a-question-you-already-voted-on-results-in-a-blank-dialog?rq=1).

Comment: @JasonC Sounds similar. The dialog isn't completely blank though, it contains a loading spinner.

Comment: If you click the loading spinner, does the app crash?